# How to pass variables from argparse to a separate configuration file?

Tags: python

I have a `sales_report.py` file and a `sales_report_config.py` file.

The `sales_report.py` file uses `argparse`, which enables the user to select a `start_date` and `end_date` from the command line when invoking the script.

The `sales_report_config.py` file contains a string `sql_query` that's used to (as you might have guessed) define a SQL query.

When the `sales_report.py` file is called, it:

1. connects to a Postgres database
2. issues a SQL query (based on the `sql_query` string defined in the `sales_report_config.py` file)
3. returns the result of the query and creates a Pandas dataframe

I'd like to pass the command line arguments `start_date` and `end_date` into the `sql_query` string in the `sales_report_config.py` file.

My basic code is:

**sales_report.py**

```
import argparse
from sales_report_config import sql_query

def parse_args():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('start_date')
  parser.add_argument('end_date')

  return parser.parse_args()

args = parse_args()

# establishes a connection to the Postgres database
connection = pg.connect(host = host,
                        port = port,
                        database =database,
                        user = user,
                        password = password)


# creates the SQL query string
query = sql_query

# creates a Pandas dataframe with the data retrieved from Postgres
df = pd.read_sql(query, con = connection)
```

**sales_report_config.py**

```
##[SQL_QUERY]

sql_query = """

SELECT
    *
FROM
    sales
WHERE 
    created_at >= {start_date} AND created_at <= {end_date}

"""
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined
```

When I try to import `start_date` and `end_date` into the `sales_report_config.py` file, I get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'sql_query' from partially initialized module 'sales_report_config' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

How do I make this happen?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After implementing the change suggested by @Mohammad Momeni, the stack trace becomes:

```
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\sales_report.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sales_report_config import sql_query
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\sales_report_config.py", line 81, in <module>
    created_at BETWEEN '{start_date} 00:00:00.000001' AND '{end_date} 23:59:59.999999')
NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined
```

Comment: I thought your files are only as shown in the post, it seems there's an error referencing line 81 of sales_report_config.py which is not the part mentioned in the post. Please add all the lines related to the last error. There should be an invalid use of `start_date`

Comment: @Mohammad Momeni - the `sales_report_config.py` file is mentioned in the post (edited).  (originally, I had .cfg... but it's 'config').  Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Can you please upload both files (complete project in a .rar) somewhere and put the link in the post to download? As I said I do not see any lines 81 or 20 in those short portions of code blocks you have mentioned.

Comment: This is code intended to run in a production environment.  I've abstracted away everything you don't need.  At the end of the day, the problem we're trying to solve is seemingly trivial:  pass a value from argparse to a string to be used in a configuration file called by the main .py file.

Comment: Yeah ok, after all, I posted the way you can do so. Then check for how you're using start_date without defining it or in any invalid usage. The error is referencing somewhere you have not posted I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Python string formatting in your `sales_report_config.py`. So where you're using `sql_query` variable, you should define the formatted variables such as `start_date` and `end_date`.

```py
query = sql_query.format(start_date=args.start_date, end_date=args.end_date)
```

Comment: When I change `query = sql_query` to the suggested `query = sql_query.format(start_date=args.start_date, end_date=args.end_date)`, I get the same error `NameError: name 'start_date' is not defined`.

Comment: @zeroes_ones Do you run the code in the correct format like `python sales_report.py 22 33`? and please mention the full stack trace in order to detect which line of the file has caused the error.

Comment: Yes, the sales_report.py is run as follows:  `C:\Users\me\Desktop>python sales_report.py 2022-10-03 2022-10-05`.  I will post the full stack trace up above. ^^